# json structure for bulk insert not valid

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman

```
Elasticsearch version : 7.1
Postman version : 7.8.0
```

`Elastic Search Url`: http://localhost:9200/menu/_bulk

`mapping`

```
 "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "input": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "output": {
                    "properties": {
                        "category": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "item": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "category": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "item": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "modifiers": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "modifiers": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "quantity": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Error I am receving:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
    },
    "status": 400
```

`Expected Result`: Successfully adding new documents to index `menu`

`Procedure`

I am trying to a bulk insert with `elastic search`. I have referred to the documentation and this is an example they provided below.

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "testindex", "_type" : "somerandomtype", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "somefield" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "testindex", "_type" : "somerandomtype", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "somefield" : "hello hello hello" }
```

I have based my formatting in the same manner but I keep getting the error. This is what my `body` looks like thats going into `postman`.

```
{"index": { "_index": "menu", "_type":"_doc" } }
{"input": "angus-burger", "output": {
"category": "Sides", "item": "Angus-Deluxe Burger", "modifiers": [], "quantity": 1} }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json format is indeed incorrect. Postman body section will show error with given Json.
Additionally Bulk request body is not meant to be in single valid Json.

Use the same data with curl, and result will be success.

Moreover, when using the command data with POSTMAN, each 'section' should be within a single line (i.e. each line represents a single valid json). Moreover, there should be no blank lines.
(there are some similarities here to 'bcp' command)

So, this would work

```
 {"index": { "_index": "menu", "_type":"_doc" } }
 {"input": "angus-burger", "output": {"category": "Sides", "item": "Angus-Deluxe Burger", "modifiers": [], "quantity": 2} }
```

But this won't work in postman for bulk insert

```
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "menu",
        "_type": "_doc"
    }
}
{
    "input": "angus-burger",
    "output": {
        "category": "Sides",
        "item": "Angus-Deluxe Burger",
        "modifiers": [],
        "quantity": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "your json format not correct .you can copy the code and check "
>   Visit http://json.parser.online.fr/ regularly!

Comment: The format to insert into elasticsearch is it's own version of json. It will not be valid if you compare it to standard json.

Comment: I was able to solve on my own and just to prove to you the formatting is different, I am still failing in the `JSON validator` you posted but it posts successfully in elastic search

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the format of the body was incorrect. After posting the below, I was able to successfully post to elasticsearch. One thing to note is that in postman, you must have it so each line is as close to the other. By that I mean you must have no spacing between your body at the end of a new line.

```
{"index": { "_index": "menu", "_type":"_doc" } }
{"input": "angus-burger", "output": {"category": "Sides", "item": "Angus-Deluxe Burger", "modifiers": [], "quantity": 1} }
```